# sed extract all matches on a line between 2 strings

Tags: regex, shell, sed

If I have a text line like:

```
Here is a replace_script_start.scriptinjection1.python.replace_script_end string and here is replace_script_start.scriptinjection2.groovy.replace_script_end another string
```

I would like to extract the content between "replace_script_start" and "replace_script_end" using sed. I tried a lot of patterns but unsuccessful, closest I got was using this:

```
echo 'Here is a replace_script_start.scriptinjection1.python.replace_script_end string and here is replace_script_start.scriptinjection2.groovy.replace_script_end another string' | sed 's/[^<]*replace_script_start.\([^<]*\).replace_script_end[^<]*/\1\\n/gp'
```

I would like sed to output:

`scriptinjection1.python`

`scriptinjection2.groovy`

Any help would be appreciated.
Note-: Looked into **grep** and **awk** as well (which worked for me), but would prefer to make this happen with **sed** if possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try `gnu grep`:

```sh
grep -oP '(?<=replace_script_start\.).+?(?=\.replace_script_end)' file

scriptinjection1.python
scriptinjection2.groovy
```

A `sed` is not an ideal solution but since it has been asked here is `gnu sed` in 2 steps:

```sh
sed -E 's/replace_script_start\.|\.replace_script_end/\n&\n/g' file |
sed -En '/^replace_script_start\./,/^\.replace_script_end/{//!p;}

scriptinjection1.python
scriptinjection2.groovy
```

Comment: is there any way to do it using sed? As stated in the question grep and awk work but would like to use 'sed' if possible.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -n '/replace_script_start\./{s//\n/;s/.*\n//;s/\.replace_script_end/\n/;P;D}' file
```

Matching on a string is problematic in these cases, so reduce the problem by replacing the strings by a unique character, then use these characters as separators.

N.B. The solution matches on `replace_script_start.` and `.replace_script_end` i.e it matches on a prefix/suffix period as well.

Answer (score 0):

First use the start tag for putting all parts on different lines.
Next remove the end tag and everything behind it.

```
echo "your_line" | sed 's/replace_script_start/\n/g'| sed -n 's/replace_script_end.*//p'
```